# How can I remove the close button from editor tabs in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, editor

I'd like to remove the close buttons from tabs in Eclipse 3.6.1.  The close button is unnecessary (middle-click closes tabs) and annoying (makes it easy to close tabs by accident).  Also, space is reserved for each close button to appear when a mouse-over event occurs so it makes the tabs wider than necessary.

Is there some tweak/hack that can disable this feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed a feature request to add an option to remove the close buttons from the tabs:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362176

Please comment on that RFE. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Removing the Close button is possible via CSS:

As example, see: 
[image]

More details:

To remove the close button, first check your Preferences > General, to ensure the Styling is enabled.

1) Locate your current css. In my case the path is:

```
eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.0.v20160718-0743\css\e4_classic_win7.css
```

2) Add the CSS code to disable the close button

```
CTabItem {
    swt-show-close: false !important;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a setting for this in Eclipse but you could (if you wanted it bad enough :P) take the Eclipse source code, edit them out and compile your own version.

Comment: Definitely not going to go the compile-myself route, no time for such extreme measures, however I am hoping someone knows some variable in one of the hundreds of config files of Eclipse that can be changed for the desired results.  If not, then one day, when I am *extremely* bored I might embark on making a plugin that reaches in through the plugin API and re-configures the tabs (if that is doable at all).